# Change default cursor when changing column width in DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, cursor, size

When I change column width, the cursor type is changed to Cursors.SizeWE.

Can it be changed to any other type?

Answer (score 0):

Inside the ColumnWidthChanged event, set it to be whatever cursor you want.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.columnwidthchanged.aspx

Be careful, because you're changing user experience that people have become accustomed to.